# How can I create the combinations from a list in python?

Tags: python

I want to create the combinations CM from the list C:

```
 C = [9, 6, 10, 4, 8, 5, 7, 2, 3]
```

it is necessary that :

```
CM=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0],
    [0,0,0,0,6,0,0,9,0],
    [0,0,0,0,6,0,0,9,10],
    [0,0,4,0,6,0,0,9,10],
    [0,0,4,0,6,0,8,9,10],
    [0,0,4,5,6,0,8,9,10],
    [0,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    [2,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Comment: so the final list is ordered and the previous lists have 0 placeholders?

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple loop with a set:

```
# get unique values in order
l = sorted(set(C))
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

seen = set() # to keep track of seen values
out = []
for x in C:
    # add new value to set
    seen.add(x)
    # update new values, else 0
    out.append([x if x in seen else 0 for x in l])

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 10],
 [0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 10],
 [0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 9, 10],
 [0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 10],
 [0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

You could also use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) (here keeping a column for 1, although the exact logic is unclear):

```
C = [9, 6, 10, 4, 8, 5, 7, 2, 3]

a = np.zeros((len(C), max(C)), dtype=int)

a[np.arange(len(C)), np.array(C)-1] = C

out = np.maximum.accumulate(a, axis=0).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but here is my answer with no imports required

```
C = [9, 6, 10, 4, 8, 5, 7, 2, 3]

C_ = C.copy() ## create a sorted copy of C
C_.sort()

z = [0 for i in C] ## list of zeros to populate CM

CM = [] ## placeholder for final list

for v in C: ## go through C
    z = z.copy() ## copy itself 
    idx = C_.index(v) ## get index of v
    
    z[idx] = v ## put v in list at this index
    
    CM.append(z) ## add to list
```